# How to determine date grouping? Month or weekday?

Tags: weekday

I have a data set listing activities over a year (in logistics context).
I can see that the loads are much more different across day of the week (e.g. Wednesdays are super busy while Sundays are very empty), but a teammate argue that grouping by month is a better idea (e.g. Jan vs Dec).

I wonder if there is any appropriate statistical analysis to prove which grouping is more appropriate?

Thanks,

Comment: This is [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for Stack Overflow, which is for programming questions. A more appropriate place for this question would be https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Do agree with that, I didn't know about that. Will do so, and thank you @costaparas